# Compile error of TeX in .rmd file to create .html

Tags: r, r-markdown, tex

I made a `.rmd` file for a vignette containing TeX scripts for my package.

My procedure

1. Make a vignette as `.rmd`file.
2. Make a `.html`file by the R script `devtools::build_vignettes()` or `devtools::document()`
3. Open the resulting `.html` file via web browser [Chrome]
4. I found that the tex script is raw in web browser page, that is, it is **not** compiled yet.

Why does such phenomenon occur ? Now, compile goes well, but a few hours ago, it failed.

Does the following relate ?

```
    > devtools::build_vignettes()
    Building mypkgName vignettes
    Warning message:
    In system(paste(cmd, "-n")) : 'make' not found
  Movin   aaa.html, bbb.html, ccc.html, aaa.R, bbb.R, ccc.R to doc/
Copying aaa.Rmd, bbb.Rmd, ccc.Rmd to doc/
Building vignette index
```

Comment: I'm confused about the flow you're trying to use; as I understand it, Rmarkdown files are usually converted to proper markdown and then converted to html and tex/pdf using pandoc. So what kind of TeX scripts are you putting in your markdown, what is it supposed to do, and what do you mean by "the compile of TeX"? Also, I'm confused by where the problem is, it "goes well in Rstudio viewer" but not in Chrome?

Comment: Sorry :'-D I think so too. I rewrite the following; My procedure is (1) make a vignette as `.rmd`file. (2) make a `.html`file by the R script `devtools::build_vignettes()` (3) Open the resulting `.html` file via web browser [Chrome] (4) I found that the tex script is raw, that is not compiled yet.

Comment: Yes, but what tex script are you using, and why would you expect it to do anything? It's not being run through tex at all if you're compiling to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most raw LaTeX and raw HTML is just passed through Pandoc without changes.  There are some exceptions:  math in dollar signs (e.g. `$x^2$`) will be handled by MathJax, which can handle a subset of LaTeX.

Even if you're dealing with this subset, you will see what looks like raw LaTeX if MathJax can't run.  This could happen if you have Javascript turned off in your web browser (maybe by [NoScript](https://noscript.net)), or if you can't connect to the MathJax website and haven't asked to reference a local copy of MathJax.

Comment: Thank you for reply, in your comment saying  _"you can't connect to the MathJax website"_  means that if there's no internet, then the tex compile always fails in `.html` file ? Actually, in my house, there is no net,  and the compile failed in my house. No internet cause this tex compilation issue ? So, now, here, I am in Cafe, where I have a network environment and compilation goes well.

Comment: You can get it to work by including a copy of MathJax locally.  See <https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#mathjax-equations>.  Note that this can't be included in the .html file, it will be in a separate file locally.

Comment: I will try to include your suggesting copy in my package so that user can see the `.html` file with compiled TeX under no internet environment.